# Spark GraphX get shortest path between all vertices

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

In Spark GraphX the `ShortestPaths` does not take an `RDD` as an input but `Seq`

This means the following does not work:

```
val paths = ShortestPaths.run(graph,graph.vertices)
```

However my graph is too large to call `collect` on and I do not want to slow this down by forcing it onto the driver only. Is there a work around for this using a `map` or `aggregateMessages`? Or am I going to have to rewrite the path finding code myself?

Comment: What about simply transforming it, then?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#toDF(scala.collection.Seq)

Comment: @Michal I'm not sure what you mean? GraphX cannot work with Dataframes.

Comment: Well there used to be a way of converting RDD simply by `toSchemaRDD()`, but it has been deprecated and the doc says that `toDF()` is the function to use now.

Comment: @Michal I do not want dataframes. `ShortestPaths` expects `Seq` not a DF.

Comment: Well the problem is that `Seq` isn't distributed...so I'm afraid you'll have to collect it then.

Comment: Or you can use GraphFrames - https://databricks.com/blog/2016/03/03/introducing-graphframes.html

Comment: @Michal I have tried to use graphframes before and it did not work at all for me... I may try it again, but GraphX feels far more stable. Additionally their `bfs` algorithm suffers from similar parallel issues.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example and show what is not working exactly? Only `graph.vertices` need to be a `Seq`.

Comment: @mtoto That's the problem, I cannot convert `graph.vertices` to `Seq` because my graph will not fit on the driver.

Comment: That is intended, because `Spark`'s implementation of the shortest path algorithm is the single destination version, where you are supposed to supply only target vertices you are interested in.

Comment: @mtoto So I have to implement this myself then?

Comment: @mtoto how do we do shortest path single destination with spark? Can we do it using pregel in spark with single source and single destination?

Answer (score 0):

I have to confess that your goal doesn't make sense to me. Are you looking for a map of, to use plain language, Vertex -> List of (Other Vertex, Shortest path to Other Vertex)? For me, shortest path questions always involve a relatively small subset of vertices, so the `Seq` makes sense to me.

Regardless, I think you will need to use the `Pregel` [object](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.Pregel$) to calculate the shortest paths yourself using the Bulk Synchronous Parallel approach pioneered by the original [Pregel paper](https://kowshik.github.io/JPregel/pregel_paper.pdf) from Google and [Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/) from Facebook. [Here](http://note.yuhc.me/2015/03/graphx-pregel-shortest-path/) is a post on doing shortest-path using BSP with `Pregel` in GraphX.

Comment: I'm doing de novo assembly using De Bruijn graphs. We generate all paths between all vertices and then keep paths above a certain length.

Comment: I defer to your superior expertise. I'm not aware of any other approach to this than the BSP-based approach I describe. I hope others chime in with easier ideas.